# Silverlight detect wether loosing focus is because tab is pressed or mouse is clicked

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there a way in silverlight to detect when a lost focus event is triggered if this 
happens because the tab key is pressed or the user presses a mouse button on another control.

This is what i want to achieve:

I have a RadGridView with 1 row. In the last column i have a numeric input, when
an user tabs out of this control, a new row should be added to the sourcecollection in the viewmodel, this automaticly adds a new row to the grid, then the first column on this row should have focus and the dropdownlist in the celledittemplate should be opened.

When i use the lost focus event adding the new row works fine, though this also works when i don't use tab to unfocus the control. Also, the first column on the new row is not selected, it somehow
gives focus to row 0 column 0.

Comment: Thomas, You reduced my accepted solution points, How you accepted your own solution? I think you should update question to add answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, inspired by the answer Dipak gave I came up with a slightly different solution,
I handled the Gridviews keydown and keyup events, keydown sets a bool to true, keyup to false.

the execution sequence fortunately is keydown, lostfocus, keyup
so in the lost focus event I only need to check wether the bool is true;
strangely enough the keyup event is not always triggered, but since the lostfocus is
I set the bool to false there also.

Comment: I think this is work around, but should have wait until some one suggest more elegant way.

Comment: You are right, since the product we're creating needs to be finished very soon I will just do it this way for now.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can trace it, Provided you have implemented mouse up/down event on each focusable element on your screen. You will have flag to check if mouse preview event up/down happen on any element, if not then its TAB key which cause lost focus.

This is work around if some one not suggest proper solution.